# If it doesn't rain, I will come

Tags: reported-speech, conditionals, backshifting

At 1 PM:

Friend: John, will you come to the party with us? (the party is at night)

John: If it **doesn't** rain, I **will** come. (looking at the weather forecast for the day, which predicts rain at night)

At 3 PM:

Friend: (Mike told me) John said that if it **doesn't** rain, he **will** come.

Suppose *it rained that night*, and so John didn't go the party. After the party ends, someone asks to one of his friends "why didn't John come to the party?"

Friend: (Mike told me) John said that if it **didn't rain/hadn't rained**(??), he **would come/would have come**(??).

Which one is correct?

Comment: after the fact: hadn't rained, would have come

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BEFORE, said at a present time:

If it doesn't rain, he will come. Possibility
If it didn't rain, he would come. Less possibility.

AFTERWARDS, said in reference to a past time:

If it hadn't rained, he would have come. [would've come]